# How to make single bar as 3d effect in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I m having following code for creating single rectangle.

How to make 3d effect for rectangle using d3.js

I need output like following picture
[image]

My code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rect</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar_div"></div>
<script>
bar();
function bar(){
  var bar_column =d3.select("#bar_div")

  var bar_rect= bar_column.append('svg')
                          .attr('class','decile-column')
                          .attr('width','200px')
                          .attr('height','30px')
  bar_rect.append('rect')
          .attr('width',160)
          .attr('height','20px')
          .attr('y', '4')
          .attr('fill',"skyblue")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This link may be helpful http://bl.ocks.org/camio/5087116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an isometric projection, (rather than a true 3D projection which has a solution given in the comment above), you'd need to draw 3 rectangles, 2 of them shear transformed by 45 degrees (or whatever angle you like) and offset accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7aos9og/2/

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var rect3d = svg.append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate (50,50)")
;

var rh = 20, rw = 200, ang=45;

rect3d.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "forward")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", rw)
  .attr("height", rh)
  ;

  rect3d.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "top")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", rw)
  .attr("height", rh/2)
  .attr ("transform", "translate ("+(-rh/2)+","+(-rh/2)+") skewX("+ang+")")
  ;

  rect3d.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "side")
   .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", rh/2)
  .attr("height", rh)
  .attr ("transform", "translate ("+(-rh/2)+","+(-rh/2)+") skewY("+ang+")")
  ;
```

It might be worth looking into http://jdan.github.io/isomer/ if you intend to do lots of these, though it works only on a canvas element rather than svg.